# How to handle same query on server and client with getMeteorData()?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I recently started working with Meteor (in combination with React), but there's something I can't get my head around.

Let's say there is a view where the user will see his 'Stuff', but an admin account will see all 'Stuff'.

On the client I have this code:

```jsx
getMeteorData() {
    let handle = Meteor.subscribe('myData');

    return {
      stuffReady: handle.ready(),
      stuff: handle.ready() ? Stuff.find({},{sort: {'createdAt': -1}}).fetch() : undefined
    };
},
```

On the server I have my publish method:

```jsx
Meteor.publish('myData', function () {
    if (this.userId) {
        // if admin show all, otherwise show users stuff
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'], 'default')) {
            return Stuff.find({},{sort: {'createdAt': -1}});
        }
        else {
            return Stuff.find({'creator._id': this.userId}, {sort: {'createdAt': -1}});
        }
    }
});
```

This is working fine for the admin. The user though can see all Stuff for like 1s before the list gets filtered and he can only see his Stuff.
I think this is the expected behaviour, since I do a query for all data in the return method of getMeteorData().

My question though: how can I return the right data for the user straight away?
I don't want to do a "admin check" in the client code for obvious reasons.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the admin check under ```Meteor.publish``` is defined on the server side, so thats ok.

Comment: This should not happen, unless you do something like changing the user's permission from Admin to Normal User from a server console. Can you elaborate on the way the test is conducted and in what context is the subscription done?

Comment: When I load the app on that view it seems okay. When I go to other views where there are other subscriptions loading "stuff" and go back to this view the problem described occurs..

Comment: So it is probably data from the other publications that was not yet fully removed. The handle can be ready even before the `unsub` takes full effect.